# How do I attach a binary to $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add in Powershell, without using a filepath

Tags: powershell, smtpclient

I have a snippet of Powershell code that allows me to specify a filename and path to attach a file into my email I want to send. The code works fine, but I do not wish to use $fileNameAndPath and want to provide raw binary data (in combination with mime type, if applicable).

```
# Attach file and send SMTPMessage
$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($filenameAndPath)
$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

Suppose binary data is stored in $binary, and the mime type is stored in $mimetype.
How can pass or convert them so that I can make a System.Net.Mail.Attachment object? Can anyone help me with a snippet ?

Answer (score 4):

The `Attachment` type has a constructor that takes a `Stream` object - and you can construct a stream object from a `[byte[]]` buffer with the `MemoryStream` class:

```
$contentStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream(,$binary)
$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($contentStream, "application/octet-stream")
```

Comment: When I print the $binary variable in powershell displays it as a list of decimal numbers. Is it supposed to be that way? What should the $binary input look like ?

Comment: @starbyone Integers or fractions? If they're all integers between 0 and 255 then everything is fine. I noticed in a comment on the other answer you said the file you receive by email "isn't correct" - what's "incorrect" about it?

Comment: The binary came from Invoke-Sqlcmd command didn't have a MaxBinaryLength set, so the limit was always 1kb. The binary variable was indeed list of integers between 0-255, however they needed to be casted to byte array , i.e. [Byte[]]$binary for the System.IO.MemoryStream. Don't know why though.

Comment: @starbyone sounds like a problem unrelated to this question :)

Comment: Yes, indeed, I created a seperate question about it. Your solution should indeed work even if $binary displays a list of values 0-255, but in my particular case I had to cast it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same class itself. `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` class have [multiple overloads for the constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.attachment?view=net-5.0#constructors).

```
New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($binary, $mimetype)
```

I assume that you need [Attachment(String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.attachment.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Mail_Attachment__ctor_System_String_System_String_) which Initializes a new instance of the Attachment class with the specified content string and MIME type information and it has the following signature.

```
public Attachment (string fileName, string? mediaType);
```

If the content is in bytes you can refer @Mathias R. Jessen answer to construct the Attachment object.